# XPath preceding-sibling to find child based on parent's sibbling's value?

Tags: html, xpath, axis

I have the following content:

```html
..

<div id="list">
  <div>
    <input id="input_randomnumber"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="input_randomnumber">Text To Match</label>
  </div>
</div>

..
```

I want to select the input, for which there is a label with a certain text. I tried to solve it using xpath and *preceding-sibling*, but I'm not getting it to work. How can I use an axis selector as a filter?

Clearly the below solution is not even valid:

```xml
(//div[@id="list"]/div/preceding-sibling::div[span[text()="Text To Match"]])/input
```

---

### From the answers below, these solutions work:

Using axis:

```
//div[@id = 'list']/div[following-sibling::div[1]/label = 'Text To Match']/input
```

Using @for and @id match, which is rather elegant (but performance?):

```
//input[@id = //label[text()="Text To Match"]/@for]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to select the input, for which there is a label with a certain text.

Here's something you can try:

Selecting by the text of the `<label>`:

```
//input[@id = //label[text()="Text To Match"]/@for]
```

Selecting by the `for` attribute of the `<label>` and the `id` attribute of the `<input>`:

```
//input[@id = //label[@for="input_randomnumber"]/@for]
```

Comment: The first solution works very well actually. How does it perform compared to the currently accepted answer?

Comment: `//` is indeed known to not being performant, but worrying about it now seems a little of [premature optimization](http://www.google.com/search?q=premature+optimization) - at least to me that don't know your use case. Anyway, through `//` is the only way to reach the `label` regardless of where it is located. If performance is a problem **and** you know the `label`s will always have more or less the same position in relation to the `input`, you can tweak the expression a little, such as in: `//input[@id = ../..//label[text()="Text To Match"]/@for]` (which would work for your example).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `//div[@id = 'list']/div[following-sibling::div[1]/label = 'Text To Match']/input`.